# Integrar código javascript em aplicação Web usando GeneXus

Tags: genexus

Na aplicação que vou fazer usando GeneXus vou precisar de desenhar diagramas e também pegar nos dados na BD e gerar diagramas. Eu já desenvolvi a ferramenta de desenho de diagramas em javascript e precisava agora de saber como integrar esse código javascript numa aplicação web desenvolvida em GeneXus. Como o posso fazer? Onde posso encontrar a informação necessária para conseguir fazer esse tipo de integração?

Eu já assisti aos videos online em genexus training mas não é referido nesses videos como se faz isso que eu pretendo fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor maneira de integrar o seu código JavaScript em GeneXus é através da criação de um controle de usuário ([User Control](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?4940)).

Outra possibilidade é adicionar o código JavaScript embutido em um TextBlock, mas a abordagem de Controle do Usuário é mais flexível e mantém o seu código GeneXus mais limpo.

O CSS pode ser personalizado modificando o tema ([Theme Object](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?4447)).

Comment: É isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Embora a maneira recomendada é usar User Controls, outra forma é embutir a fonte js no cabeçalho da página.
Veja
[JavascriptSrc Property](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?JScriptSrc%20Property,)

Comment: Olá! Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Poderia traduzir sua resposta para o Português? Que é o idioma oficial do site.

Comment: Okay me parece bem. Me sabe dizer o porquê de eu editar o JScript Runtime Render e o código nunca ser atualizado? Eu edito xls Design Render e consigo ver a atualização de acordo com as modificações feitas, mas no caso do JScript Runtime Render por mais que edit não consigo ver as modificações atualizadas no web panel onde uso o User Control.